# Time needed to travel to Proxima Centauri in 2050 and technology behind

Tags: science-based, hard-science, space-travel, near-future

Given:

- current (2020 year) knowledge and science status of human-kind and
- that human-kind and human science development will occur in exactly the same way as it did so far,

how long will a ship travel to [Proxima Centauri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxima_Centauri) *in 2050* and what engine it will be equipped with?

No science-fiction, no technobabble, please, just a pure science. I just want to predict how will space travel engineering go in the next thirty years and how development of this part of science influence / reduce (if at all) time needed by a regular space ship to reach Proxima Centauri.

Comment: do you realize that  human-kind and human science development will occur in exactly the same way as it did so far could also mean that flat-earthers go to power and ban space research for being a waste of taxpayers money in fabricating CGI?

Comment: The problem with science is that it isn't on a predictable path. Some parts are, like progress of computer chips was for years, but with something like space exploration there are still too many options open.

Comment: @Trioxidane, according to an infographic I saw some time ago, if space travel would have progressed at the same pace as computer did, today a one way trip to the moon would take 1 minute instead of the 3 days it took to the Apollo

Comment: Predictions are difficult, especially those about the future. (And the very idea of a *science-based* prediction of technological development over thirty years is unsound.) This question is the canonical prototype for "purely opinion based". (Example: there is a ten years old child in Outer Mongolia named Tömör Baatar, who wil study physics and engineering, and in 2032, at the age of 22, will emigrate to Australia, where he will set up a space transportation company, which in 2036 will introduce a new revolutionary electrohydrodynamic engine with enormous thrust and specific impulse, etc.)

Comment: On that timescale (just 30 years to launch ?), probably  the already proposed [Project Orion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Tiny, cm sized probes, accelerated by lasers

It's called [Breakthrough Starshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakthrough_Starshot), and it's a method of getting a probe to Proxima Centuri in 20 to 30 years, with a 4 year allowance for data reply.

#### Did you mean manned? We could totally attempt a one-way generation ship if properly motivated, yet 100% odds we wont.

If an inspirational leader (JFK-like) were to commit to this task and then die tragically in a way which inspired the human race to unite, we could totally do this. (Looks at USA politics - this isn't going to happen.)

A lunar mining operation assembling a large ship for a long distance manned space mission has been planned seriously and in detail since Wernher von Braun [published his research in 1948's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mars_Project). 110 years after the first rocket left the atmosphere, we have the know how to do this, just there are more important things taking our attention. And to be honest I kinda agree - humanity has better things to do than leave towards Alpha Centuri by 2050.

However were to unite to do it, the process would be similar to Von Browns "Marsprojekt":

- An assembly plant on the moon mining aluminium, titanium, iron, silicon, and oxygen, refining them, creating parts, and transporting them up a [lunar space elevator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_space_elevator), which is well within current engineering.
- Assembled in lunar orbit. The ship is quite large and could never land on a planet. Room for about 400 people. Stockpiled with more things than I can think to list.
- Nuclear reactor powered for fuel
- Ion thrusters for thrust. [Current record for Ion thruster use in space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster) is a 486kg ship using 74kg of fuel to get 4.3km/s of delta-v. So a 1:1 fuel/payload ratio can get 28km/s delta V. You'll be resupplying on the way so no need to carry all the fuel you need now.
- Use the starshot system for first launch - basically put a massive nuclear reactor in space or on the moon, and use laser propulsion against a solar sail to accelerate the ship for as long as possible.
- Once out of range of laser start using Ion thrusters to accelerate.
- As soon as the ship departs, lunar assembly factory starts building supply pods. Put fuel, spare parts, extra medicine, emergency rations, seeds for hydroponics, gifts from random internet strangers, anything and everything. The pods are much smaller than the ship, so, can be accelerated to a faster speed than the ship and will catch up to it.
- Pods will need to get smaller as time goes by to ensure that they still catch up to the faster moving ship. Eventually you'll need to build supply pods with booster rockets because your laser will not be powerful enough, and then you'll need to start building larger ones again - the ship slows down so the pod speed should also decelerate to match.
- Ship receives pods and refuels and resupplies constantly from the stream of supply pods being sent. We're talking at least ~10,000 supply pods here, mostly full of fuel and with a few spare parts of every system sent pre-emptively. Any new tech breakthroughs should also be sent.
- 100 full refuels of the fuel tank from pods could give 3000km/s of delta V, plus gravity assist when exiting the solar system (~15km/s), and the initial laser burst (~100km/s)
- 50% of your fuel will need to be used for deceleration - which will make it easier to intersect with your future supply pods. Precise calculations will allow the pods meet the ship when the fuel is needed with minimal difference in delta V.
- Back of envelope suggests about 600 years to get there.
- Don't return. The trip is one way. Set up an orbit, descend in landing ships, and set up a civilisation.

Comment: I think it would be impossible to get any sort of generation-ship past planning phases no matter the circumstances (unless Earth's destruction is imminent for some reason) because it's reasonable to assume that by the time it would arrive, a faster ship built later would've beaten the original ship. Why build a ship that can make the trip in 600 years today when you can spend 100 years developing technology that cuts the trip down to 200 years?

Comment: @Dragongeek - But why send a 200yr rocket if we can wait 50yrs for a 100yr rocket? At some point you have to take the risk and go for it. If they depart and shortly after a revolution in engine tech is discovered - Send that 200yr engine in a supply pod 100yrs later, They'll get it 150years later - allowing the ship to speed up for the last 300 years in 100. I don't think technology will jump **that much**, but I would expect improved retrofitted parts to be made and sent to improve things several times.

Comment: Sure, eventually there might be a point where the two lines converge giving future historians a retrospective optimum construction and launch date, but then again, the technological rate of progress has been increasing steadily (eg Moore's law which is exponential) since the industrial revolution and shows no signs of stopping or slowing down. We're nowhere near "the end of science" and I think it's quite possible that the convergence point won't be reached untill the trip time is measured in seconds or days via teleportation/warp drive or whatever

Comment: Why we are saying that for **4.25 ly** Proxima Centauri "back of envelope suggests about **600 years** to get there", if Project Daedalus assumes that **6 ly** Barnard's Star is reachable within **50 years**? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The propulsion system will be chemical rocket engines. The ship will also use gravitational slingshot assists to gain its maximum velocity of fifteen (15) kilometres per second.

This is the space technology as it exists today in 2020. The human species has been able to employ space technology to do exactly this since the 1970s. It is unlikely to change in the next thirty years.

A spacecraft launched in 2050 to Proxima Centauri will take 82,000 years to travel there. This is what it will take at 15 kps.

In the wake of the Global Financial Collapse and the current Pandemic it is unlikely that there will be massive investments in space technology to improve our capacity for interstellar travel. Therefore, the scenario outlined above is the most one.

Answer (score 3):

**It highly depends**

You don't give enough insight into what exactly we want. In theory, any vessel that can leave the solar system can reach Proxima. It will just take a metric ton of time.
Furthermore, how big is the vessel anyways  Is it suppose to make a fly by or shall it also do something there ?

Lets assume this: The Vessel should reach Proxima in 25 Years, the Ship with fuel has a mass of 1000 Tons and it is suppose to do something in the system. Whatever that may be.

**Transfer Speed**

So we want to reach Proxima in 25 Years. Light takes 4,2 Years to go there, so we take around 6 Times longer. Meaning or peak Velocity is 1/6 the Speed of light. Which is 50.000 km/s. At those kinds of speeds, any trajectory is a line from A to B.

**Got to go fast**

So sure, we could build fancy ass lasers or something but lets be real. Nobody is going to fund that. There is a more, shall we say elegant solution. Nukes. A Standard US Nuclear Warhead weighs 1,100 kg and releases an energy equivalent to 1,2 million tons of TNT, which is 5 peta-joules.

Sure, all of this energy doesn't really go in one direction, but that can be changed. Thermonuclear bombs actually use the gamma ray burst of a normal nuke to start the Fusion Process. Thus, we can "Control" the blast of a nuke to a certain extent.
Let's say we can use 0.1% of the energy from each blast to accelerate the craft. That would be around 1.200 Tons of TNT, which is 5020,8 Gigajoules of energy. Which is the same as Newton, and as F = m*a goes we can figure out that a single blast would give us 5020.8 km/s² in terms of Acceleration.

Of course, this ain't gonna happen like this. No craft would be able to do this. But the theory is proven. Sure, we cannot use a big bomb to get us there, but a lot of small ones would do the trick.

Or fuel is nothing else than just a lot of small nukes. Depending on how good we can build the Shock absorption, we may be able to get 500m/s² for each Blast. But I don't know that.

**The Interstellar Void**

So we have build a ship and blasted it into Interstellar space at 50.000km/s. What now ?

Well let's first talk about a shield. This one is easy, the ship just flips around after it has reached peak velocity. The shield it used to absorb the nukes will be more  than enough.

I would assume the ship would not shutdown during the trip. Many systems would be in a low power state but there is still a lot to do.

The ship itself can still make some changes to its path, but at this point there is no real point in that.

**Another happy landing**

So 25 Years have passed and the ship sort of needs to get a lot slower. The Nukes will do the trick just fine. I would however advice to have more Nukes with you then needed. You don't want a single faulty nuke to be the end of the mission.

As soon as the craft is in orbit, it can use the leftover nukes to go to some places or maybe it uses an Ion drive to fly around. This just depends on the Mission. If the ship is supposed to just look at one planet, we may be able to nuke it from Earth to that planet in a direct assent style. I would guess this is what we would end up doing just because the more things you add, the more things can break.

But if the ship is supposed to fly around, i would assume the Ship wouldn't stop in an Orbit around one star. I could see us planning out a voyager Style Path where the Vessels sling shots from A to be in a very controlled way. This way it doesn't need the Nukes and can just stop at a Planet that is interesting. This is also the most flexible path as we can easily tell the craft to go somewhere else. Because we will have new Info 25 Years down the line.

**Communication**

The vessel would constantly relay Information back to earth. If i had to guess, i would say a few dedicated relay probes get send ahead and after the Vessel has launched. Really power relays that are not intended to slow down. These can be used to send a backup with a stronger signal in  the case some data gets corrupted during the journey back to Earth.

**AI**

Needless to say, this is vessel controls itself. It has to make decisions and will probably resemble the most advanced AI in the history of humanity on launch day. I could see us using two AI´s that sort of Argue with each other. One that is supposed to be more Risky and one that is supposed to be very safe thinking.

Anyways, the AI(s) will have a set of goals that they need to achieve. But they will also have to power to overwrite or Instructions. There is no point in chasing a goal if the AI can see that another option is way better.

And tbh, I wouldn't even instruct the AI to not nuke planets if it thinks that has any value. I can't think of any but the damage this one vessel can do is very limited. So don't put any restrictions on it.

Now the last question is, what happens when the fuel runs out? Will the ship de-orbit ? I say no. The final goal should be to reach a parking orbit. The insights of this Ship can teach us a lot about Interstellar Travel and besides, it will still have energy for a bit. Thus I´d say the AI should be instructed to reach a parking orbit around the most interesting object and just sort of wait and observe.

So yeah, this is how we could get there in 25 Years.

- Also sorry for the bad english

Comment: I gotchu with grammar, as soon as the edit is approved.